# Understanding specs of PNP transistor for replacement

Tags: transistors, pnp, specifications

I want to replace an ON Semicondutor [BC557](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/BC556B-D.PDF) PNP transistor with a Multicomp [BC557](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1693079.pdf) PNP transistor. It is just for general switching of LEDs. But the specs look different although they are same mode.

Why are voltages from Omsemi transistor are negative while those of Multicomp transistor are positive?

Can I still replace it with that one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can - its the same device.

Convention - print PNP voltages as negative, NPN types positive

Comment: +1. As far as I know, Multicomp is not a manufacturer, it's just a trader. I know them almost exclusively from Farnell. It seems the brand label Multicomp serves one main purpose: Lots and lots of unbranded parts appear to be made under one roof... This is why I tend to not take their data sheets too seriously (and sometimes enjoy finding the original one that got copied-and-pasted).

Comment: @zebonaut - very true and when things get copied there's always the danger of someone screwing it up. (+1 for making a good point)